# Chromium «падает» через 5 минут после запуска в Kali 2.0

Tags: linux, google-chrome

*Хромиум* «падает» через 5 минут после запуска в *Kali 2.0*:

```
libGL error: failed to open drm device: Отказано в доступе
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
[21051:21051:0814/165352:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(345)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process
[253:254:0814/165612:ERROR:channel.cc(300)] RawChannel read error (connection broken)
[277:278:0814/165628:ERROR:channel.cc(300)] RawChannel read error (connection broken)
[21026:21047:0814/165652:FATAL:audio_manager.cc(93)] Check failed: false.
Аварийный останов
```

что бы это могло быть?

```
# dpkg -l | grep chromium
ii  chromium                               44.0.2403.89-1~deb8u1                amd64        web browser
ii  chromium-dbg                           44.0.2403.89-1~deb8u1                amd64        web browser - debugging symbols
ii  chromium-inspector                     44.0.2403.89-1~deb8u1                all          web browser - page inspection support
```

Причём, все ошибки вываливаются сразу, но только после появления этой строки:

```
[2264:2285:0814/171436:FATAL:audio_manager.cc(93)] Check failed: false. 
Аварийный останов
```

«Падает» с Аварийной остановкой...

```
# chromium --version
Chromium 44.0.2403.89 Built on 8.1, running on Debian Kali Linux 2.0
```

На *kali1* «падений» не было. `chromium_37.0.2062.120-1~deb7u1_amd64.deb`

---

Дополнение:

Думал это какой-нибудь сайт где биткоины раздают по 700 Сатоши на халяву так шалит, у меня был открыт такой - freebitco.in. Оставил один Facebook, вроде не падает, потом поигрался с остальными сайтами - всё равно падает.

Затем сел, и на петле 127.0.0.1 - пол часа играл в свою собственную самописную игру. Всё журчит. После этого пошёл в chess.com порубиться в шахматы и одной партии не успел сыграть как меня выкинуло. Я любитель играть в пули, быстро-быстро перезапускаю, "restore session", доигрываю, опять выкидывает. Так вот, пока в шахматы играл - 3 раза выкинуло. Проиграл 9 очков какому-то Норвежцу.

Всегда "Падению" предшествует `[22402:22426:0814/184601:ERROR:channel.cc(300)] RawChannel read error (connection broken)`, после этого пол минуты молчка - затем audio_manager.cc - и бах.

---

Огромная благодарность @alexander barakin
Сделал дебаг как тут https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Debugging советуют

`chromium --debug 2>&1 | tee gdb-chromium.txt` pastebin.com/rXhEUSRP

`chromium --debug --single-process 2>&1 | tee gdb-chromium.txt` pastebin.com/BHicjSTX

`ldd /usr/lib/chromium/chromium` www.pastebin.ca/3104538

Два падения, один без сингл-процесс, другой с. Оба падения с одной лишь вкладкой chess.com и двумя проигранными играми ));

побрёл я оформлять баг-репорт. сюда отпишусь как тикет закроют. Спасибо.

Точно не помню, но кажется на kali1 я лечил это тем, что скачивал ubuntu-шный пакет chromium-а - и всё. Никто не знает как быстро костыль забить?

[Тикет открыт.](https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=2534)

Тикет через 2 минуты был закрыт таким администратором:

```
(0003759)
muts    (administrator)
2015-08-14 18:02

    erm, closed.
```

Comment: я думаю, что в багрепорте желательно воздержаться от локализованных строк. т.е. перед запуском команд в *shell*-е присвойте переменной `LC_ALL` значение `C`, выполнив команду: `export LC_ALL=C`.

Comment: Исправил. Но к сожалению на pastebin превысил 10 пастов в 24 часа, так что ldd на левый pastebin положил...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для тех, кого волею судеб занёс сюда google, в поисках решения этого вопроса.

```
[21026:21047:0814/165652:FATAL:audio_manager.cc(93)] Check failed: false.
Аварийный останов
```

Из-за этой ошибки `chromium` падает. Он запущен не от `root` и не может получить доступ в Kali2 к аудио карте.

Т.е. всего-навсего, надо добавить пользователя, который запускает `chromium` в группу `audio`.

Баг забивается костылями так:

На чистой Kali2, только что загруженной с dvd-диска и с установленным `chromium`, по сети или ещё как, выполняется следующее:

```
# pidof pulseaudio | xargs kill -9
# /bin/echo "autospawn = no" >> /etc/pulse/client.conf
# /usr/sbin/adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" chromuser
# /usr/sbin/adduser chromuser audio
```

Далее,

```
# su chromuser
$ chromium
```

Вуаля!

Answer (score 2):

> что бы это могло быть?

это баг.
рапортовать о нём следует сюда: https://bugs.kali.org

как получить необходимую для баг-репорта информацию, написано, например, [здесь](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Debugging).

Comment: для баг репорта как то вообще мало информации. Я пытаюсь отловить сайт на котором оно крошится, но пока что, похоже что, крошится на всём, причем рандомно, 1 минута - 30 минут, сейчас тестирую чисто на петле 127.0.0.1. Может посоветуете как там дебаг включить, что им присылать то в репорт? dmesg что ли?

Comment: например, [так](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Debugging)

Comment: Премного благодярен.

Comment: Всё вроде, материал подобрал, Вам не трудно взглянуть верно/неверно. И такой вопрос, а как им послать баг репорт, если у меня нету gmail ящика?

Comment: `aptitude show chromium` кажет мне такую строчку `Сопровождающий: Debian Chromium Maintainers <pkg-chromium-maint@lists.alioth.debian.org>` прямо туда кинуть?

Comment: но они же не kali. тут какая-то путаница получается конкретная.

Comment: @kali2fan, ошибка происходит в дистрибутиве *kali*. верно? то, что они пользуются пакетной базой другого дистрибутива — не столь важно в данном случае.

Comment: так, а как определить майнтанера по хромиуму для kali? они скорей всего его тупо копируют с дебиана, он по дефолту не стоит, я его подкачиваю ручками...

Comment: @kali2fan, а зачем вам мэйнтэйнер? это что, требуют у вас в багтрекере bugs.kali.org?

Comment: *я его подкачиваю ручками* — что значит «подкачиваете ручками»? вы скачиваете откуда-то файл с пакетом и устанавливаете его с помощью dpkg? тогда багрепорт, конечно, слать бессмысленно. куда угодно — бессмысленно.

Comment: а там такое: `Block reason: Access from your Country was disabled by the administrator.`... Видимо - Санкции, Путин, Крым... ааа / "подкачиваете ручками" значит в консольке набираю `aptitude install -y chromium`. Естественно с нативного репозитария.

Comment: *Block reason: Access from your Country was disabled by the administrator* — кстати, отличный повод навсегда забыть про существование этого дистрибутива.

Comment: Это не они, kali бы так не поступили, не их стиль. Это площадка где у них тикет-система хостица, какая-то `Sucuri WebSite Firewall - CloudProxy - Access Denied`, ладно, я сейчас ториком обойду это.

Comment: @kali2fan, *kali бы так не поступили, не их стиль* — значит, повод написать ещё один багрепорт. уже по поводу сетевой инфраструктуры дистрибутива.

Comment: +1 ............. тор они тоже фильтруют, ищу носки (;